# Change Mouseover Color using html layers

Tags: html

I created text as a transparent png using photoshop. I place my png images within Layers. Is there a way to change mouseover color in this case?

```
<div id="layer14" style=
"position: absolute; width: 122px; height: 20px; z-index: 14; left: 14px; top: 643px">
<a href="the%20son.html"><img class="auto-style15" height="20" src=
"graphics/Buttons/the%20son2.png" width="122"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to copy and paste the html code into my question box, but it doesn't show up

Comment: thanks. so, what do you think about modifying this code to include change in color upon mouseover?

Comment: I think that you should ditch images for text and use HTML / CSS as the browser is intended for :) [Here is a basic example](http://jsbin.com/papevi/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

read this for mouse hover image changing. You could do the same thing with two images of different colors.

http://helplogger.blogspot.com/2012/05/create-rollover-image-effect-change.html

But the code is this...

```
<a href="URL ADDRESS"><img src="URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE" onmouseover="this.src='URL OF THE SECOND IMAGE GOES HERE'" onmouseout="this.src='URL OF THE FIRST IMAGE GOES HERE'" />
```